# SQL quoting error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a table using this Syntax

**MySQL**

[image]

But then as you can see, there's a red underline on "text".
I have tried using **text.'tblemployee'**, **'text.tblemployee'** , etc.
None of them worked.

Am I missing something here?

p.s : this is my first post ever, sorry if it is not really descriptive, Cheers.

Comment: 'text.tblemployee' should work

Comment: Please include your code as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Developer, I have tried it, it ended up underlining both words.

Comment: You need to quote with backticks not quotes ```

Comment: use without quotes like  `text.tblemployee`

Comment: @piet.t sorry, i will edit the post now, I thought you can see the red underline(error) better with pics.

Comment: @lad2025 Ohh, that's why, i must have learnt it wrong then, thanks heaps!

Comment: @Dharan i usually do that, but then i was curious how to put quotes on the text, anyway thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the symbol apostrophe(') with the back quote(`)